# Do I need to do a get for every field of a document I want to access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I see that to get a field of a document in security rules one must use get. The example below shows getting the 'admin' field of some document in the users collection. If I wanted to get another field, would I have to do another get request or can I just do one get request and get all the fields I need in the document.

Here is the example I'm referring to in the documentation.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

```
service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /cities/{city} {
          // Make sure a 'users' document exists for the requesting user before
          // allowing any writes to the 'cities' collection
          allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))

          // Allow the user to delete cities if their user document has the
          // 'admin' field set to 'true'
          allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to write another get().  There are no variables in Firestore security rules, so you can't store the contents of a get() in order to use its data multiple times.

Multiple gets accessing the same document might not incur multiple read charges.  The documentation states:

> Some document access calls may be cached, and cached calls do not count towards the limits.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I appreciate your fast response. That indeed was my main concern, multiple gets incurring unnecessary read charges. In the previous example from the documentation, would it be the case (or probably be the case) that if you did another get on the same document it would be cached? Thanks again.

Comment: The documentation doesn't make any guarantees about this.  I would suspect it's highly likely that it would be cached, but if the documentation doesn't state that it definitely will be cached, then you shouldn't make assumptions about that.